# Importing a CSV file with commas in my rows into mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, csv

I really hope this question hasn't been asked and answered before but I can't find a single clear SO answer on it so here goes.

I am trying to import a CSV file into a mongoDB collection. The CSV file contains word definitions, which often include commas. I want to be able to store these data points in mongodb with their commas and be able to read them with their commas in a javascript app.

When I import the csv into mongoDB, it reads these commas as an indication to go on to the next field. I have tried using double quotes around each of my observations but to no avail - instead this imports as three quotation marks (""") and mongoDB still takes the comma within that observation as an indication to move on to the next field.

Please help!!

(For clarity I am using the simplified GUI through mongoDB compass...but happy to use the command line if there is a solution!)

Example of the CSV:

[image]

Comment: Please post an example of your CSV

Answer (score 1):

You might try using the command-line tool, [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) for more options than the MongoDB Compass import interface has.